# Simple code that links to page and fills form

Tags: forms

Intro: I am completely new to coding but I am hoping this is quite easy.

I have a Wordpress site.  On it I want to have a link to the following page:

https://kahoot.it

but what I want to do is that the link will go to that page and automatically enter a "Game PIN" and take me to the page after that.

Each link on my WOrdpress site will have within it a different Game Pin to take me to a different game.  So for example the first link will be to "Quiz A" and the Game PIN embedded within that link will be (say) 12345.
A link under it will be to "Quiz B" which will have the PIN 24680

So clicking the link effectively skips the Game Pin page.

etc..
etc..

Is this easy to do and how would I then incorporate the code into the Wordpress page?

Thanks

Comment: Possible to use Kahoot's [sharing feature](https://kahoot.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/285167-how-to-share-kahoots) to generate a link? Maybe that doesn't work with pins, not sure.

Comment: Yes I see that.  But what my son wants to do is tell his friends to go on his wordpress site and click on the link.  Then they just add their username (which is the page after the Game PIN) and they are ready to go...